# php arrays get the order number of a certain element

Tags: php, arrays

Lets say i have an array in PHP

```
$test['michael_unique_id'] = 3;
$test['john_unique_id'] = 8;
$test['mary_unique_id'] = 10;
.
.
.
.
$test['jimmy_unique_id'] = 4;
```

(the values (3,8,10.........4) are unique)

Lets say i want to search for the unique id 10, and get the order of the matching element in the array. In this example, the third element has the value 10, so i should get the number 3.

I can do it by scanning with a for loop looking for the value i'm searching and then get the $i value when i have a match, but i wonder if there is any built-in function (or a better method) that implements this.

Comment: I don't believe that there is a function, as the idea behind a dictionary array is to be able to access a certain element by its key (in your example the key 'mary_unique_id' and not 3, which you may find by `array_search(10, $test)`). Could you explain, what you want to accomplish with your code?

Comment: As @Lars says, there is no such function; however, to do this efficiently, you should make sure you exit the for loop as soon as you find a match.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get all of the array's values as an array with `array_values()` and then use `array_search()` to get the position (offset) of that value in the array.

```
$uniq_id  = 10;
$all_vals = array_values($test);  // => array(3, 8, 10, ... )
echo array_search( $uniq_id, $all_vals ); // => 2
```

Because PHP array indices are zero-based, you'll get 0 for the first item, 1 for the second item, etc. If you want the first item to be "1," then just add one. All together now:

```
$uniq_id = 10;

echo array_search( $uniq_id, array_values( $test ) ) + 1; // => 3
```

It's not clear to me, however, that this is necessarily as performant as just doing a `foreach`:

```
$uniq_id  = 10;
$idx      = 1;

foreach($test as $val) {
  if($val == $uniq_id) {
    break;
  }

  $idx++;
}

echo $idx; // => 3
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, `array_search` will give you the key, but in your case, you want the index of that key, so I believe a loop is your best bet.  Is there a good reason why you need the index?  It doesn't seem very useful to me.

Comment: Maybe he is using parallel arrays for different properties with only common link being the index (3rd element across all parallel arrays define properties of a single object/entity).